# Using mutexs and semaphores outside of the main

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

I had a question about using mutexes and semephores outside of the `main()` function and using them in another .c file where I have all my functions defined. I'm wondering where I should declare

```
pthread_mutex_init();
pthread_mutex_destroy();
sem_init();
sem_destroy;
```

Can I declare these once at the top of the file and the destroys at the bottom? Or do I need to wrap these around every function I have defined like this?:

```
void function(){
    pthread_mutex_init();
    sem_init();

    pthread_mutex_lock();
        ///code
    pthread_mutex_unlock();

    pthread_mutex_destroy();
    sem_destroy;

}
```

Comment: Initialize the mutex once, before any thread uses it, and destroy it after all threads have finished.  Do not destroy a mutex that some other thread might concurrently be trying to lock.

Comment: You should #include semaphore.h and pthread.h to extern those functions.  Remember to add -lpthread on the command line to link in the pthread libraries.

Comment: @NateEldredge in the main function then? The creation of the threads is in the main function, but the functions that have the critical sections are in another file.

Comment: @aLitteBetter It doesn't matter in what file objects are declared and initialized. Order in *time* of initialization and usage matters.